# Executing a net use command

Tags: java, process, batch-file, runtime.exec

I need to execute a net use command which is written in a batch file to enable a drive. Batch file is as follows:

```bat
net use * /delete /Y
net use l: \\<windows drive name> /user:<domain>\<username> <password>
```

The above batch file enables a drive for me and its visible as L: drive to me.
I need to execute this batch file through java code and then write the some files onto this drive.

I am using the below code to execute this batch file:

```
String[] array = { "cmd", "/C", "start", "C:/file.bat" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(array);
```

Problem is when I try to access the drive to write the files it gives me a path not found exception. Sometimes it runs and sometimes it doesn't.

Friends can anyone help me to understand where is the issue. What wrong step I am performing. In case I am not clear with my question do let me know.

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes it runs and sometimes it doesn't.

This looks like a race condition. [`Runtime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) executes your command in a separate process, while the calling application continues to run. It is then undefined whether the batch file has already completed or not when you try to access the file.

`Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process` object, which you can use to communicate with the sub process. In your case, it should be sufficient to wait for the process to complete:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(array);
p.waitFor();

// Now, your batch file should be completed and you can continue
// ...
```

Comment: This also sounds very plausible!

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for the reply. Its working for me. However, one thing I would like to update in this. For the very first time I ran the code it stalled and I had to forcibly stop the execution. After that when I re-ran the code it worked. I again ran it then also its working.
So, the concern is as I have to use this logic in an application how can I assure myself that it runs every time its invoked.

Comment: You would need to add some kind of monitoring to make sure that the command completes within a specific time frame, and otherwise terminate and re-execute the command. You can add this to your code (for example by implementing a Watchdog thread), but if possible I would take a look at the Apache Commons Exec project mentioned by @demaniak which provides such monitoring out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect when that hits the actual command shell, windows does not like the "/". Maybe try "\" instead?
External process execution is a bit tricky - you might want to look at [Apache Commons Exec project](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) to help you out there.

Comment: Thanks Demaniak, I have used your suggestion as well with the code.